# Terraform update Cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, terraform

I am using Terraform to deploy (and update) a cloud front distribution. The deployment works perfectly, but by the second time i deploy, it creates a new CF distribution, instead of updating the previous one.

I have been using this [reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html) to create the terraform file, but it says nothing about updating a distribution.

I suspect that the creation of a new distribution, instead of the update of the previous one, is related to the origin_access_identity (OAI). It looks like it is creating a new OAI every time, which is than used as the origin.

Edit: I hardcoded the OAI using the one from the previous deployment,

```
        s3_origin_config {
        # origin_access_identity = "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.oia.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
        origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/E3IILPWMC6EHO"
    }
```

to see if this would update the distribution, but no, it keeps creating it from scratch.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Terraform code:

```
# Input variables
variable "AWS_PERSONAL_ACCESS_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_PERSONAL_SECRET_KEY" {}

# Configure the provider
provider "aws" {
    access_key = "${var.AWS_PERSONAL_ACCESS_KEY}"
    secret_key = "${var.AWS_PERSONAL_SECRET_KEY}"
    region     = "us-east-1"
}

# add variable to remove circular dependencies
variable "bucket_name" {
    type = "string"
    default = "scf-website"
}

# Configure the IAM policy
# The bucket must be accessible ONLY to OIA, and not to users directly!
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
    statement {
        effect = "Allow"
        actions = ["s3:GetObject"]
        resources = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/*"
        ]
        principals {
            type = "AWS"
            identifiers = ["${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.oia.iam_arn}"] 
        }
    }
}

# Create a bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "a_static_website" {
    bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
    # acl    = "public-read"
    acl     = "private"
    policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json}"

    website {
        index_document = "index.html"
        error_document = "error.html"
    }
}

# Upload index.html
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "index_page" {
    bucket  = "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.bucket}" 
    key     = "index.html"
    source  = "index.html"
    # this ACL should be reevaluated. Should the file still be public ???
    # acl    = "public-read"
    acl     = "private"
    content_type = "text/html"
}

# Upload error.html
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "error_page" {
    bucket  = "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.bucket}" 
    key     = "error.html"
    source  = "error.html"
    # this ACL should be reevaluated. Should the file still be public ???
    # acl    = "public-read"
    acl     = "private"
    content_type = "text/html"
}

# Create Origin Access Identity
resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "oia" {
    comment = "This resource has only one argument, comment, and it is optional."
}

# Configure the CloudFront distribution
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cfd" {
    enabled         = true
    is_ipv6_enabled = true
    default_root_object = "index.html"

    origin {
        domain_name      = "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.bucket_regional_domain_name}"
        origin_id        = "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.id}"

        s3_origin_config {
            origin_access_identity = "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.oia.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
        }
    }

    # without this, aws returns their default error, instead of the one defined by us
    custom_error_response { 
        error_code = 404    
        response_code = 200
        response_page_path = "/error.html"  
    }

    default_cache_behavior {
        allowed_methods         = ["HEAD", "GET"]
        cached_methods          = ["HEAD", "GET"]
        target_origin_id        = "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.id}"
        viewer_protocol_policy  = "redirect-to-https"

        forwarded_values {
            query_string = false
            headers = ["Origin"]
            cookies {
                forward = "none" 
            }
        }
    }

    restrictions {
        geo_restriction {
            restriction_type = "whitelist"
            locations = ["US", "CA", "GB", "DE"]
        }
    }

    viewer_certificate {
        cloudfront_default_certificate = true
    }
}
```

Terraform plan:

```
      id:                                                                                                   <computed>
      json:                                                                                                 <computed>
      statement.#:                                                                                          "1"
      statement.0.actions.#:                                                                                "1"
      statement.0.actions.2071725391:                                                                       "s3:GetObject"
      statement.0.effect:                                                                                   "Allow"
      statement.0.principals.#:                                                                             "1"
      statement.0.principals.~3303760437.identifiers.#:                                                     <computed>
      statement.0.principals.~3303760437.type:                                                              "AWS"
      statement.0.resources.#:                                                                              "1"
      statement.0.resources.1943396215:                                                                     "arn:aws:s3:::scf-website/*"

  + aws_cloudfront_distribution.cfd
      id:                                                                                                   <computed>
      active_trusted_signers.%:                                                                             <computed>
      arn:                                                                                                  <computed>
      caller_reference:                                                                                     <computed>
      custom_error_response.#:                                                                              "1"
      custom_error_response.2936347672.error_caching_min_ttl:                                               ""
      custom_error_response.2936347672.error_code:                                                          "404"
      custom_error_response.2936347672.response_code:                                                       "200"
      custom_error_response.2936347672.response_page_path:                                                  "/error.html"
      default_cache_behavior.#:                                                                             "1"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.allowed_methods.#:                                                 "2"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.allowed_methods.0:                                                 "HEAD"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.allowed_methods.1:                                                 "GET"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.cached_methods.#:                                                  "2"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.cached_methods.0:                                                  "HEAD"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.cached_methods.1:                                                  "GET"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.compress:                                                          "false"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.default_ttl:                                                       "86400"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.field_level_encryption_id:                                         ""
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.#:                                                "1"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.563318458.cookies.#:                              "1"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.563318458.cookies.2625240281.forward:             "none"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.563318458.cookies.2625240281.whitelisted_names.#: "0"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.563318458.headers.#:                              "1"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.563318458.headers.0:                              "Origin"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.563318458.query_string:                           "false"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.forwarded_values.563318458.query_string_cache_keys.#:              "0"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.lambda_function_association.#:                                     "0"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.max_ttl:                                                           "31536000"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.min_ttl:                                                           "0"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.smooth_streaming:                                                  ""
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.target_origin_id:                                                  "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.id}"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.trusted_signers.#:                                                 "0"
      default_cache_behavior.~1523641885.viewer_protocol_policy:                                            "redirect-to-https"
      default_root_object:                                                                                  "index.html"
      domain_name:                                                                                          <computed>
      enabled:                                                                                              "true"
      etag:                                                                                                 <computed>
      hosted_zone_id:                                                                                       <computed>
      http_version:                                                                                         "http2"
      in_progress_validation_batches:                                                                       <computed>
      is_ipv6_enabled:                                                                                      "true"
      last_modified_time:                                                                                   <computed>
      origin.#:                                                                                             "1"
      origin.~3433826240.custom_header.#:                                                                   "0"
      origin.~3433826240.custom_origin_config.#:                                                            "0"
      origin.~3433826240.domain_name:                                                                       "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.bucket_regional_domain_name}"
      origin.~3433826240.origin_id:                                                                         "${aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website.id}"
      origin.~3433826240.origin_path:                                                                       ""
      origin.~3433826240.s3_origin_config.#:                                                                "1"
      origin.~3433826240.s3_origin_config.~2934106515.origin_access_identity:                               "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.oia.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
      price_class:                                                                                          "PriceClass_All"
      restrictions.#:                                                                                       "1"
      restrictions.811065190.geo_restriction.#:                                                             "1"
      restrictions.811065190.geo_restriction.1303118592.locations.#:                                        "4"
      restrictions.811065190.geo_restriction.1303118592.locations.0:                                        "US"
      restrictions.811065190.geo_restriction.1303118592.locations.1:                                        "CA"
      restrictions.811065190.geo_restriction.1303118592.locations.2:                                        "GB"
      restrictions.811065190.geo_restriction.1303118592.locations.3:                                        "DE"
      restrictions.811065190.geo_restriction.1303118592.restriction_type:                                   "whitelist"
      retain_on_delete:                                                                                     "false"
      status:                                                                                               <computed>
      viewer_certificate.#:                                                                                 "1"
      viewer_certificate.69840937.acm_certificate_arn:                                                      ""
      viewer_certificate.69840937.cloudfront_default_certificate:                                           "true"
      viewer_certificate.69840937.iam_certificate_id:                                                       ""
      viewer_certificate.69840937.minimum_protocol_version:                                                 "TLSv1"
      viewer_certificate.69840937.ssl_support_method:                                                       ""

  + aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.oia
      id:                                                                                                   <computed>
      caller_reference:                                                                                     <computed>
      cloudfront_access_identity_path:                                                                      <computed>
      comment:                                                                                              "This resource hasonly one argument, comment, and it is optional."
      etag:                                                                                                 <computed>
      iam_arn:                                                                                              <computed>
      s3_canonical_user_id:                                                                                 <computed>

  + aws_s3_bucket.a_static_website
      id:                                                                                                   <computed>
      acceleration_status:                                                                                  <computed>
      acl:                                                                                                  "private"
      arn:                                                                                                  <computed>
      bucket:                                                                                               "scf-website"
      bucket_domain_name:                                                                                   <computed>
      bucket_regional_domain_name:                                                                          <computed>
      force_destroy:                                                                                        "false"
      hosted_zone_id:                                                                                       <computed>
      policy:                                                                                               "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json}"
      region:                                                                                               <computed>
      request_payer:                                                                                        <computed>
      versioning.#:                                                                                         <computed>
      website.#:                                                                                            "1"
      website.0.error_document:                                                                             "error.html"
      website.0.index_document:                                                                             "index.html"
      website_domain:                                                                                       <computed>
      website_endpoint:                                                                                     <computed>

  + aws_s3_bucket_object.error_page
      id:                                                                                                   <computed>
      acl:                                                                                                  "private"
      bucket:                                                                                               "scf-website"
      content_type:                                                                                         "text/html"
      etag:                                                                                                 <computed>
      key:                                                                                                  "error.html"
      server_side_encryption:                                                                               <computed>
      source:                                                                                               "error.html"
      storage_class:                                                                                        <computed>
      version_id:                                                                                           <computed>

  + aws_s3_bucket_object.index_page
      id:                                                                                                   <computed>
      acl:                                                                                                  "private"
      bucket:                                                                                               "scf-website"
      content_type:                                                                                         "text/html"
      etag:                                                                                                 <computed>
      key:                                                                                                  "index.html"
      server_side_encryption:                                                                               <computed>
      source:                                                                                               "index.html"
      storage_class:                                                                                        <computed>
      version_id:                                                                                           <computed>


Plan: 5 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: What does the plan output look like?

Comment: basically it says "Plan: 5 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy." @ydaetskcoR

Comment: That's not showing it replacing the Cloudfront distribution, it's showing that it doesn't think it exists yet so it is creating it from scratch. What are you doing with your state?

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what is happening. I am doing nothing with the state, but should I? Its one of my first times using terraform, and I am still learning... @ydaetskcoR

Comment: Your question is overly specific and missing the main point then. I think you're just missing some state stuff so you need to go back through guides on how to manage state and maybe rework your question to show a simpler example if you're still stuck with it. If you choose to do this, explain the steps you have performed (any commands executed) and the results at each step and explain how you aren't getting the result you want and what you do want.

Comment: Well, your comment pointed me in the right direction. This behaviour results from me not saving the state file. I was using circleCi to manage the deployment and forgot to save the state file. Now I am doing the deployment from my machine, and it saves the state file in local directory, and on the next deployment it updates the distribution, instead of recreating it. Thank you for your help @ydaetskcoR